# python concat multiple columns if next column not in previous column

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a sample data like this:

```
col1                    col2        col3
PYTHON RD              APT 3         NaN
STACK AVE APT 2-3    APT 2-3         NaN
OVER ST 1/2         UNIT 1/2    UNIT 1/2
FLOW RD                  NaN         NaN
```

I want to create a new field:

```
col1                    col2        col3               COMBINED
PYTHON RD              APT 3         NaN        PYTHON RD APT 3
STACK AVE APT 2-3    APT 2-3         NaN      STACK AVE APT 2-3
OVER ST 1/2         UNIT 1/2    UNIT 1/2   OVER ST 1/2 UNIT 1/2
FLOW RD                  NaN         NaN                FLOW RD
```

I tried:

```
columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
COMBINED = ''
for col in columns:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna("")
    COMBINED = COMBINED + df[col].str.strip() + ' '
    df['COMBINED'] = COMBINED.str.strip()
```

Above one can combined but with duplicated in second observations `STACK AVE APT 2-3 APT 2-3`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(
    df[["col1", "col2"]]
    .fillna("")
    .apply(
        lambda x: x.loc["col1"]
        if x.loc["col2"] in x.loc["col1"]
        else x.loc["col1"] + " " + x.loc["col2"],
        axis=1,
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
                col1      col2              COMBINED
0          PYTHON RD     APT 3       PYTHON RD APT 3
1  STACK AVE APT 2-3   APT 2-3     STACK AVE APT 2-3
2        OVER ST 1/2  UNIT 1/2  OVER ST 1/2 UNIT 1/2
3            FLOW RD       NaN               FLOW RD
```

---

EDIT: For many columns:

```
def combine(x):
    out = []
    for word in x:
        if word and not any(word in w for w in out):
            out.append(word)
    return " ".join(out)


columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
df["COMBINED"] = df[columns].fillna("").apply(combine, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                col1      col2      col3              COMBINED
0          PYTHON RD     APT 3       NaN       PYTHON RD APT 3
1  STACK AVE APT 2-3   APT 2-3       NaN     STACK AVE APT 2-3
2        OVER ST 1/2  UNIT 1/2  UNIT 1/2  OVER ST 1/2 UNIT 1/2
3            FLOW RD       NaN       NaN               FLOW RD
```

Comment: if I have more than 2 cols, like `col1`, `col2`, `col3`. It is difficult to modify the code each time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this covers all your caes:

```
def combine(row):
    row = row.fillna("")
    result = row["col1"]
    for col in ["col2", "col3"]:
        if not row[col] in result:
            result += " " + row[col]
    return result
    
df["COMBINED"] = df.apply(combine, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try play with unique and join

```
df['col4']=df.fillna('').apply(lambda X:",".join(X.unique()).strip('\,$'),axis=1)


     

            col1       col2         col3                  col4
0          PYTHON RD     APT 3       NaN            PYTHON RD,APT 3
1  STACK AVE APT 2-3   APT 2-3       NaN  STACK AVE APT 2-3,APT 2-3
2        OVER ST 1/2  UNIT 1/2  UNIT 1/2       OVER ST 1/2,UNIT 1/2
3            FLOW RD       NaN       NaN                    FLOW RD
```